# Making connection between ipv6 to ipv4

Tags: ipv6

I am trying to learn ipv6 .So i have lot of doubts on  ipv6 .I already read about ipv6 transition mechanism.My doubt is how a ipv6 host can communicate with ipv4 host through ipv4 network.I read  about tunneling,its using for communicating ipv6 hosts over ipv4 network.So how we can communicate ipv6 host to ipv4 host.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 forms.

- **Dual stack**: Your network hardware runs IPv4 and IPv6 simultaneously.
- **Tunnel**: This means taking IPv6 packets and encapsulating them in IPv4 packets. This is outlined in the *[RFC 4213](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4213)* "Basic Transition Mechanisms for IPv6 Hosts and Routers". There are two kinds of tunnels:
- `Manual`: Also known as static. This is the best for connecting corporate IPv6 intranets over the Internet. It's not good for other IPv6 problems. Each IPv6 packet is encapsulated inside IPv4 packets. This kind of tunnel requires a double stack router.
- `Dynamic`: The dynamic tunnels use a variety of techniques to establish packet destination address and routing on the fly. This makes them far easier to create and maintain. The most popular is *6to4*, that stablish automatic connections among IPv6 networks through IPv4, usually Internet. It applies dynamically a valid and unique IPv6 prefix to each IPv6 subnet, so it let the tunnel stablish automatically.
- **NAT-PT**: Network Address Translation-Protocol Translation (NAT-PT) explained in *[RFC-2766](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2766)*. Is software or a device translates IPv6 packets into IPv4 packets. It doesn't represent a generic mechanism that would be universally applicable because it is appplication dependant.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Its worth considering them to be separate, independent networks. In most cases at a IP protocol level 'transition' is basically getting a ipv4 only host to connect to the ipv6 internet without the bits in between needing to be aware of it.

Tunneling essentially is just that - you basically set an endpoint (your system) and a server basically picks up and routes packets to you.

Native dual stack has several possible means of getting an ipv6 address to you. You'd still need to set up your systems for a seperate addressing system (SLAAC or IPV6 rd for example) and they run along side each other.

So no, a pure ipv6 system typically cannot directly talk to a ipv4 system without some form of tunneling - 4 in 6 or 6 in 4 for example.

Comment: how we can implement tunneling behind NAT

Comment: The right kind of tunnel would just work. What it is though is a matter of experimentation - I used  UDP encapsulated IPv6 tunneling with gogo6 with nat, but really experimentation is needed to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

"My doubt is how a ipv6 host can communicate with ipv4 host through ipv4 network."

While the host is starting the connection, NAT64/DNS64 without DNSSEC can be used.

Literal IPv4-addresses are not allowed in this mode. If you need literal-ipv4-addresses you need nat64 extended to 464xlat.

NAT64 is mostly implemented as NAT from IPv6 to IPv4 and stateful classical NAT to reduce the amount of public IPv4-addresses.